# In what contexts are "subject" and "issue" not interchangeable?

Tags: difference

I know both *subject* and *issue* mean a topic that people are discussing and arguing about, but there are many examples in which they cannot be used interchangeably.

So how are they different from each other? In what contexts is one or the other preferred?

Comment: Can you give any of these "examples" showing exactly what's at issue here? Obviously "you" is the "subject" of the preceding sentence, and neither "issue" in that sentence nor "subject" in this one can be replaced by the other word. We need more context.

Comment: For example: I have nothing more to say on the subject./The party was divided on the issue.

Comment: M.N: Ah, right. You want to know if there are any contexts where the two words seem to have *exactly the same meaning*, but where idiomatically we tend to use one rather than the other. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Please edit clarification into the question itself.

Comment: This can be answered using a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

OP unwittingly chose two excellent examples of where he thinks the two words are "interchangeable"...

> 1: *I have nothing more to say on the subject.*
>    2: *The party was divided on the issue.*

These totals from Google Books are relevant...

> *more to say on the **subject*** [98,400 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20to%20say%20on%20the%20subject%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    *more to say on the **issue*** [5,220](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20to%20say%20on%20the%20subject%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22more%20to%20say%20on%20the%20issue%22&tbm=bks)
>
> *divided on the **subject*** [475,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20to%20say%20on%20the%20subject%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22divided%20on%20the%20subject%22&tbm=bks)
>    *divided on the **issue*** [604,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20to%20say%20on%20the%20subject%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22divided%20on%20the%20issue%22&tbm=bks)
>
> *the **subject** was resolved* [7,430](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20issue%20was%20resolved%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20subject%20was%20resolved%22&tbm=bks)
>    *the **issue** was resolved* [106,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20issue%20was%20resolved%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

[Here's a link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20divisive%20issue,a%20divisive%20subject&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,a%20divisive%20issue;,c0;.t1;,a%20divisive%20subject;,c0) showing how *divided on the **issue*** has become far more common in recent decades, and [here's another one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20popular%20issue,a%20popular%20subject&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,a%20popular%20issue;,c0;.t1;,a%20popular%20subject;,c0) showing that *a popular **subject*** remains the more common choice.

---

Putting it all together, where the sense for both words is *area of discussion*...

> 1: ***issue*** meaning *topic, subject* has only really taken off in the past half-century.
>    2: ***issue*** is very strongly associated with *contentious* topics (more *argued over* than *discussed*).

See StoneyB's comment below for more on how "legalese" usages such as [the question at issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20issue%20was%20resolved%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22question%20at%20issue%22&tbm=bks) arose, eventually leading to what now looks like "near synonymy" in current popular use. Also note [this trend](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20issue%20in%20question&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,the%20issue%20in%20question;,c0).

Comment: This sense of *issue* derives from the original sense of "progeny, result" from legal use. To expedite trials the parties conferred with the judge to determine what factual and legal matters were actually in dispute; trial was limited to the results (issue) of this conference, the points "at issue".

Comment: @StoneyB: Excellent observation - which seems obvious as soon as you point it out, but which I wasn't consciously aware of until now. It does give me hope that many aspects of English which seem almost arbitrary (to natives and learners alike) do actually embody some degree of "logic". But as with an observation you made recently about *spelling*, any such logic is more likely to be *explanatory* rather than *predictive*. There's still much to learn, but at least the right approach could help you *remember*.

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

> The subject of conversation was.. (OK)
>
> The topic of conversation was... (OK)
>
> The issue of conversation was... (wrong)

versus

> The issue of prostitution is... (OK)
>
> The subject of prostitution is...(OK)

*Issues* tend to be more about topics discussed in the context of **action**, whereas *subjects* tend to be more about **objects of thought or discussion**.

Compare:

> It was a difficult subject to talk about.
>
> It was a difficult issue to resolve.

Now

> It was a difficult issue to talk about

is also possible, but

> It was a difficult subject to resolve.  (wrong).

is incorrect.

Comment: An *issue* is something that needs to be resolved, whereas a *subject* is just a topic of discussion.